# ssh the master ask the remote slave to run commands on salve's terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi3

As we know, the ssh connection requires command on both master and slave, the slave need to enter 'xhost' and 'sshpass' command to connect to the master. I wonder if the master can ask the slave to run the command on the terminal of the slave, so I don't need to type the command one by one on the slaves. Just let the master to inform them. The current problem is that the command must be type on the slave itself, if I type on the master, it can only run on the master, even though the slave is connected to master by 'ssh+ip' command.

Comment: you wanna login only with ssh + ip  address instead of username password port etc ?

Comment: ah I forget that. There is password in the next step I have to enter.

Comment: you just wanna login as ssh + ip address to your server?

Comment: `ssh -Xt host command` perhaps ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.